# The answer is a two-digit number

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking

> 0870678884068983409815824039880670002291

Hint 1:

> Solving this requires external resources.

Hint 2:

> The fact that both the problem and the answer are expressed as numbers is largely a red herring.

Comment: This took the xkcd boards four days to solve; I wonder how this community will do?

Comment: With our combined support, it'll be one day. Two days, tops!

Comment: @histocrat Suggest to change the question a bit (thou I have no better idea), cuz I know the answer already without thinking..

Comment: @JoeZ. I was trying to hint to histocrat what you're saying, without saying it =D

Comment: Right... I'm trying to think about it myself, though.

Comment: Heh, I assumed googling the riddle and posting the answer was against the rules of the site.

Comment: It's against the _spirit_ of the rules, perhaps, but you can't actually tell if somebody did it or not.

Comment: @FollowMyProposals Someone is going to follow that link and then post an answer without admitting they've seen it! Could you delete your comment?

Comment: @randal'thor OK. I did.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to reading a lot of books and hint #2, the answer is:

> 18

The clue is made up of

> 4 ISBN-10 numbers 
> 0870678884 - How to Win 
> 0689834098 - You Have to Write
> 1582403988 - Six
> 0670002291 - Times Three

Great puzzle!

Comment: Oh wow ... yes, great puzzle!

Comment: Make an oath that you did not google the answer, or your ding ding will shrink @JasonLepack

Comment: Ok... I did not Google the answer.  Please do not shrink my ding ding.